# Jinja Macros: passing the local variables

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

How can I pass the all local variables in a template to a macro?

I can pass var1, var 2 to macro_function like that in test.html

```
{% from 'macro.html' import macro_function  %}

{{ macro_function(var1, var2) }}
```

is there something like

```
{{ macro_function(**locals) }}
```

so that I can pass all local variables in test.html to the macro?

Comment: Does it need to be a macro? It sounds like you'd be better off using `{% include ... %}`.

Comment: @dirn thanks that is a good idea, I need to change my design a little bit

Answer (score -2):

Not sure why you would want to do that.
I would say keep definitions of template scoped variables to a minimum.
And if you need a set of variables, you can pass a dict or an object holding all relevant key/value pairs from the function that renders the macro. Then in turn pass the dict/object to the macro.